# Manage Selenium Grid queue

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, grid, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I have 1 grid hub server and 3 selenium nodes.
I would like to execute multiple test suite against **one** Grid Hub server.
So that each test suite will be executed on all 3 servers and the rest of the test suits (pending) will wait till the current test suite will finish its execution.

Can the Grid Hub manage a queue of the test suits?
If no, is there any workaround or another solution?

Answer (score 9):

**TLDR;** - Yes. Grid can manage.

**Long answer**

Selenium Hub doesn't care about whether the requests are coming from 3 different test suites or one. Think about it in this way - Hub will process all the requests that comes to it. When a request comes, hub will see if there is a node that has the capability to execute the request.

- If there is one available and free, it will send the command to the node.
- If there is a node which can execute the request but is busy now, it will send the command to the queue.
- If there are no nodes which has the requested capability, the request is marked as failed.

Hub doesn't check for the source of request anywhere in the above flow.